Generate Bearer Token for pat rest API
I am trying to generate a pat token using the Azure devops rest API. I need to pass a bearer token in the authentication under Header. I have followed this documentation to generate the bearer token but it's not working. How can I correctly generate the token and use it.


How can I correctly generate the token and use it.

You can refer to the following steps to generate the token to create PAT.
Step1: Create an AAD Application in Microsoft Entra ID -> App registrations
Step2: Add Delegated Azure DevOps user_impersonation permission in AAD Application.
For example:

Step3: Add https://jwt.ms as Redirect URI in Authentication tab.

Step4: Add the AAD Service Principal to the Organization. Refer to the steps: Add and manage service principals in an Azure DevOps organization
Step5: Run the following request to get the code:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
?client_id=<appID>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope= 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345

You can record the code value in the response:

Step6: You can use the following PowerShell sample to get the aad token.
$tenantID=""
$clientId=""
$clientSecret=""
$redirectUri="https://jwt.ms"
$code=""   # code from above step


# Azure token endpoint
$tokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Prepare the body of the request
$body = @{
    grant_type    = "authorization_code"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    scope         = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default openid profile offline_access"
    code          = $code
    redirect_uri  = $redirectUri
}

# Prepare the headers
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}

# Make the POST request
$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenUrl -Headers $headers -Body $body
echo $response2.refresh_token

Step7: You can use the aad token to generate Azure DevOps PAT.

It's showing me Need admin approval when I hit the url

@JagdishPadeliya Have you added the AAD application to your organization?

I don't have access to add the user

@JagdishPadeliya Can you check if you can set the option: Grant admin consent for AADname in AAD application -> API permissions to grant admin consent to aad app? This is required when you create the access token.

that option is greyed out

@JagdishPadeliya This option should be required. You may need to contact your administrator to help you turn this option on. Then you can do the next steps. The only contact channel we can provide help is Stackoverflow
